# 2002 mazda tribute rebuilt engine and new oil cooler doesn't fit right

Tags: oil, mazda, tribute

I recently bought a totally remanufactured engine, and to stay within warranty, they make you buy a new oil cooler.  I bought an after market one, and it doesn't fit right.  The rubber rings have been changed to a size that seems to work, but it's blown twice, spewing oil out.  Suggestions?

Comment: Buy oil cooler from Dealership and be done with it.